# Customizing maven testing classpath / classloader sequence

Tags: maven, classpath

I want to change the order of the classpath entries in maven - to ensure that resources (specifically log4.properties) are picked up in a deterministic order of my specification.

The classpath presently generated by maven has no apparent rhyme/reason.  The intent here is to prepend the default maven-generated classpath with the resources directory:

```
 classpath=<resources directory>:$MAVEN_DEFAULT_CLASSPATH
```

Actually the 'resources' directory is simply the root dir:

```
 classpath=.:$MAVEN_DEFAULT_CLASSPATH
```

How may that be achieved - preferably with options both in pom.xml and via "-D" parameters on the command line to maven?

The task here is to run tests through scalatest: we can consider it related to the maven-surefire plugin. I will double check if scalatest reuses the maven-surefire classpath.

**UPDATE** : let us clarify what *actually* is generated by maven for the classpath:

```
/Users/steve/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.2.0/hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0-tests.jar:
/Users/steve/.m2/repository/com/twitter/parquet-column/1.6.0rc3/parquet-column-1.6.0rc3.jar:
/Users/steve/.m2/repository/org/spark-project/akka/akka-slf4j_2.10/2.3.4-spark/akka-slf4j_2.10-2.3.4-spark.jar:
/Users/steve/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:
/Users/steve/.m2/repository/com/codahale/metrics/metrics-json/3.0.0/metrics-json-3.0.0.jar:
/Users/steve/.m2/repository/org/tachyonproject/tachyon-client/0.5.0/tachyon-client-\

etc ..
```

As we can see, the anticipated classpath structure - that is to have the resources directories FIRST-- is not being followed.

**Another update**  Upon suggestion by a commenter **mvn -X** was added and here is an excerpt of the more verbose output relevant to surefire and scalatest:

```
 classpath=<resources directory>:$MAVEN_DEFAULT_CLASSPATH


[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <additionalClasspathElements>${maven.test.additionalClasspath}</additionalClasspathElements>
  <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
  <basedir default-value="${basedir}"/>
  <childDelegation default-value="false">${childDelegation}</childDelegation>
  <classesDirectory default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
  <classpathDependencyExcludes>${maven.test.dependency.excludes}</classpathDependencyExcludes>
  <debugForkedProcess>${maven.surefire.debug}</debugForkedProcess>
  <dependenciesToScan>${dependenciesToScan}</dependenciesToScan>
  <disableXmlReport default-value="false">${disableXmlReport}</disableXmlReport>
  <enableAssertions default-value="true">${enableAssertions}</enableAssertions>
  <excludedGroups>${excludedGroups}</excludedGroups>
  <failIfNoSpecifiedTests>${surefire.failIfNoSpecifiedTests}</failIfNoSpecifiedTests>
  <failIfNoTests>${failIfNoTests}</failIfNoTests>
  <forkCount default-value="1">${forkCount}</forkCount>
  <forkMode default-value="once">${forkMode}</forkMode>
  <forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>${surefire.timeout}</forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>
  <groups>${groups}</groups>
  <junitArtifactName default-value="junit:junit">${junitArtifactName}</junitArtifactName>
  <jvm>${jvm}</jvm>
  <localRepository default-value="${localRepository}"/>
  <objectFactory>${objectFactory}</objectFactory>
  <parallel>${parallel}</parallel>
  <parallelMavenExecution default-value="${session.parallel}"/>
  <parallelOptimized default-value="true">${parallelOptimized}</parallelOptimized>
  <parallelTestsTimeoutForcedInSeconds>${surefire.parallel.forcedTimeout}</parallelTestsTimeou
  <parallelTestsTimeoutInSeconds>${surefire.parallel.timeout}</parallelTestsTimeoutInSeconds>
  <perCoreThreadCount default-value="true">${perCoreThreadCount}</perCoreThreadCount>
  <pluginArtifactMap>${plugin.artifactMap}</pluginArtifactMap>
  <pluginDescriptor default-value="${plugin}"/>
  <printSummary default-value="true">${surefire.printSummary}</printSummary>
  <projectArtifactMap>${project.artifactMap}</projectArtifactMap>
  <redirectTestOutputToFile default-value="false">${maven.test.redirectTestOutputToFile}</redi
  <remoteRepositories default-value="${project.pluginArtifactRepositories}"/>
  <reportFormat default-value="brief">${surefire.reportFormat}</reportFormat>
  <reportNameSuffix default-value="">${surefire.reportNameSuffix}</reportNameSuffix>
  <reportsDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports"/>
  <reuseForks default-value="true">${reuseForks}</reuseForks>
  <runOrder default-value="filesystem"/>
  <skip default-value="false">${maven.test.skip}</skip>
  <skipExec>${maven.test.skip.exec}</skipExec>
  <skipTests default-value="false">true</skipTests>
  <test>${test}</test>
  <testClassesDirectory default-value="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}"/>
  <testFailureIgnore default-value="false">${maven.test.failure.ignore}</testFailureIgnore>
  <testNGArtifactName default-value="org.testng:testng">${testNGArtifactName}</testNGArtifactN
  <testSourceDirectory default-value="${project.build.testSourceDirectory}"/>
  <threadCount>${threadCount}</threadCount>
  <threadCountClasses default-value="0">${threadCountClasses}</threadCountClasses>
  <threadCountMethods default-value="0">${threadCountMethods}</threadCountMethods>
  <threadCountSuites default-value="0">${threadCountSuites}</threadCountSuites>
  <trimStackTrace default-value="true">${trimStackTrace}</trimStackTrace>
  <useFile default-value="true">${surefire.useFile}</useFile>
  <useManifestOnlyJar default-value="true">${surefire.useManifestOnlyJar}</useManifestOnlyJar>
  <useSystemClassLoader default-value="true">${surefire.useSystemClassLoader}</useSystemClassL
  <useUnlimitedThreads default-value="false">${useUnlimitedThreads}</useUnlimitedThreads>
  <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.scalatest:scalatest-maven-plugin:1.0:test (test)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <argLine>-Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m</argLine>
  <config>${config}</config>
  <debugArgLine>${debugArgLine}</debugArgLine>
  <debugForkedProcess default-value="false">${debugForkedProcess}</debugForkedProcess>
  <debuggerPort default-value="5005">${debuggerPort}</debuggerPort>
  <filereports>SparkTestSuite.txt</filereports>
  <forkMode default-value="once">${forkMode}</forkMode>
  <forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds default-value="0">${timeout}</forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>
  <htmlreporters>${htmlreporters}</htmlreporters>
  <jUnitClasses>${junitClasses}</jUnitClasses>
  <junitxml>.</junitxml>
  <logForkedProcessCommand default-value="false">${logForkedProcessCommand}</logForkedProcessC
  <membersOnlySuites>${membersOnlySuites}</membersOnlySuites>
  <memoryFiles>${memoryFiles}</memoryFiles>
  <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
  <parallel>${parallel}</parallel>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <reporters>${reporters}</reporters>
  <reportsDirectory>/shared/hwspark/sql/hbase/target/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
  <runpath>${runpath}</runpath>
  <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
  <stderr>${stderr}</stderr>
  <stdout>${stdout}</stdout>
  <suffixes>${suffixes}</suffixes>
  <suites>${suites}</suites>
  <systemProperties>
    <java.awt.headless>true</java.awt.headless>
    <spark.test.home>${session.executionRootDirectory}</spark.test.home>
    <spark.testing>1</spark.testing>
    <spark.ui.enabled>false</spark.ui.enabled>
    <spark.ui.showConsoleProgress>false</spark.ui.showConsoleProgress>
    <spark.executor.extraClassPath>${test_classpath}</spark.executor.extraClassPath>
    <spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts>true</spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts>
  </systemProperties>
  <tagsToExclude>${tagsToExclude}</tagsToExclude>
  <tagsToInclude>${tagsToInclude}</tagsToInclude>
  <testFailureIgnore>${maven.test.failure.ignore}</testFailureIgnore>
  <testNGConfigFiles>${testNGXMLFiles}</testNGConfigFiles>
  <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</testOutputDirectory>
  <tests>${tests}</tests>
  <testsFiles>${testsFiles}</testsFiles>
  <wildcardSuites>${wildcardSuites}</wildcardSuites>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
```

Comment: Where do you need the classpath? In maven-surefire-plugin/ maven-failsafe-plugin ?

Comment: If you run tests via maven-surefire-plugin the folder `src/test/resources` or to be more accurate `target/test-classes`is the first folder on the classpath after that there will be the `src/test/java/` followed by `/src/main/resources` (target/classes`. This is defined that way. May be i misunderstand you question?

Comment: @khmarbaise  You understood the question perfectly: and your 'answer' is what I would have expected. However, the ACTUAL classpath (as seen by a print statement I added) is much different and in fact puts a bunch of unimportant jar files BEFORE those resources directories.  BTW I updated the OP to clarify based on your good comment here.

Comment: You can check in the output via `mvn -X ` and search there for `test classpath:` and you will what you are searching for.

Comment: @khmarbaise  I added -X as you state but do not find "test classpath:" in the output. THere is however LOTS more output/chattiness so -X did have a significant effect.